# jQuery: unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

could not find a solution to my problem so i'll ask here.

When i insert jQuery file, i get an error on line 2:
unexpected token ILLEGAL

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('
        <div id="style_selector">
        <div id="style_selector_container">
        // another chunk of code
        </div><!-- #style_selector end -->');
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: JavaScript does not support multi-line strings like this. Either put it on one line or escape the end with ``\``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="style_selector"><div id="style_selector_container"></div>');
});
```

This will do the job.Because while you are appending a content using jquery it must not contains new line.